# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Worksheet' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

The error says that I have a type error between 'Worksheet' and 'Int' I a unable to determine where the + sign error is. I am pulling a set of data from a website and then dropping that data into a Dataframe. I am trying to have the data append to the same excel sheet every day. I have deleted the part that creates the Dataframe "df". I have verified that the data is pulling in correctly, It is just not appending to the Excel as desired.

Error:

**File "C:\Users\djrad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_openpyxl.py", line 414, in write_cells
    row=startrow + cell.row + 1, column=startcol + cell.col + 1

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Worksheet' and 'int'**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uo
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import xlrd as xl 
from xlutils.copy import copy
import datetime as dt
from openpyxl import load_workbook as lw

   Excelpath= (r'C:\Users\djrad\Desktop\Market Rent Data\Rent_Outputs_Master.xlsx')

#Step 6: Builds DataFrame with designated headers and output lists.    
df= pd.DataFrame({'Street Address': outputstreetlist,
              'City': outputcitylist,
              'State': outputstatelist,
              'Zipcode': outputzipcodelist,
              'Price': outputpricelist,
              'SqFt': outputsqftlist,
              'Date': today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')})

print (Excelpath)
print (df)
print ('Opening Excel')
book= lw(Excelpath)
writer= pd.ExcelWriter(Excelpath, engine= 'openpyxl')
writer.book= book
start= book['Rental List']
writer.sheets= dict((ws.title,ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

ws= book['Rental List']

for row in ws.rows:
   values= [cell.value for cell in row]
   if not any (values):
       start= row[0].row-1
       break

 df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Rental List', startrow= start, index= False, header= True)

 print ('Saving to Excel')

 try:
     writer.save()
 except:
     print('The file is open elsewhere, please close it')
```

Comment: I have minimized, updated, and added the actual Typerror. Thank you for pointing out my error.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from inside pandas. The most probably cause is this line of your code:

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Rental List', startrow= start, index= False, header= True)
```

which might call `write_cells` internally:

```
write_cells row=startrow + cell.row + 1, column=startcol + cell.col + 1
```

Most likely culplit here is the `start` value you provide as `startrow = start`.

Try `print(type(start))` after getting it - then change your code to:

```
for start, row in enumerate(ws.rows,1):  # 1-based row-count in pyxl?
   if not all(cell.value == None for cell in row):
       break
```

to get the first non empty row.

---

In case enumerate does not work on `ws.rows` (it should) use

```
start = 1 # cols/rows are 1 based in pyxl? else use 0
for row in ws.rows:
   if not all(cell.value == None for cell in row):
       break
   start += 1
```